# Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute for entity type Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, customer-attribute, error-log, eav-attributes

> Actually i am getting this error while editing products from product
>   grid magento2.3
>
> Actually i deleted some custom attribute using code as
>   well as manually from backend  after this i got this error in var/log/system.xml

Answer (score 0):

> Hi guys,i found solution for this issue is nothing but we have to
>   delete attribute_id from **eav_attribute**,**catalog_eav_attribute** and based
>   on your attribute datatype you have to delete from corresponding
>   **catalog_product_entity_*** tables respectively.